# Python 3 Selenium Webdriver how cani turn repetitive actions into a funtion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have the following functions which click through different elements on a webpage.This works, however is there a better way of doing this please?

```
    def test_siteinenglish(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"requestCulture_RequestCulture_UICulture_Name\"]/option[1]").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"navbar-to-collapse\"]/ul")
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div/ul/li[1]/a").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div/ul/li[2]/a").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div/ul/li[3]/a").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div/ul/li[4]/a").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div/ul/li[5]/a").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div/ul/li[6]/a").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li/a").click()

def test_siteinfrench(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"requestCulture_RequestCulture_UICulture_Name\"]").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"navbar-to-collapse\"]/ul")
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div/ul/li[1]/a").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div/ul/li[2]/a").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div/ul/li[4]/a").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div/ul/li[5]/a").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/div/ul/li[6]/a").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul[2]/li/a").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a generic 'click' function which you can pass a paramater to.(In this case it'd be the element locator) Page Object Model design pattern should be followed for optimal test framework design